# How to wait for Future method inside widget testing?

Tags: testing, flutter, dart

I want to test my widget. In my HomePage widget, there's a method to call API then it will show the result inside this widget. Here's the code for HomePage widget

```dart
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  WebScraper _webScraper = WebScraper();

  HomePage();

  HomePage.forTest(Client client) {
    _webScraper.client = client;
  }

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List<Post> posts = [];

  bool isPostLoaded = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _onRefresh();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: RefreshIndicator(
              child: isPostLoaded ? ListView.builder(
                key: Key('post-list'),
                itemCount: posts.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Card(
                    key: Key(posts[index].id.toString()),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(posts[index].title),
                        Text(posts[index].content),
                        Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                          // some code
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ) : CircularProgressIndicator(),
              onRefresh: _onRefresh),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _onRefresh() async {
    List<Post> postFromWebsite =
        await this.widget._webScraper.getPostsFromWebsite();
    if (postFromWebsite.length > 0) {
      setState(() {
        posts = postFromWebsite;
        isPostLoaded = true;
      });
    }
  }
```

And here is my test code

```dart
void main() {
  var homeHttpMock;
  setUp(() {
    MockClient client = MockClient((request) async {
      String html =
          await rootBundle.loadString('test_resources/test.html');
      return Response(html, 200);
    });

    homeHttpMock = MediaQuery(
      data: MediaQueryData(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: HomePage.forTest(client),
      ),
    );
  });

  testWidgets('Show post inside card in the list view',
      (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(homeHttpMock);
    await tester.pump();
    final listView = find.byKey(Key('post-list'));
    expect(listView, findsOneWidget);
  });
```

I tried to use `tester.runAsync`, `tester.pump` with duration, `tester.pumpAndSettle` (this one will be timed out), and `FakeAsync` but these methods don't work for my widget test and it will lead my test to be failed.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution after refactoring my test code using @LgFranco's advice and reading carefully in this [article](https://medium.com/flutter/event-loop-in-widget-tester-50b3ca5e9fc5).

I changed my test code to this

```dart
testWidgets('Show post inside card in the list view',
    (WidgetTester tester) async {
  await tester.pumpWidget(homeHttpMock);
  await tester.pumpAndSettle(); // Wait for refresh indicator to stop spinning
  final listView = find.byKey(Key('post-list'));
  expect(listView, findsOneWidget);
});
```

And I have to run it using `flutter run my_test_code.dart` command becuase if I didn't do that, it will raise `pumpAndSettle timed out` error. Then I realized that this is not a widget test because acording to the article I read, I can't test any real async work inside my widget test.

If anyone found another solution to this problem, please mention me. Thank you.

Comment: Did you find any another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use `await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));`?

Just use the time that your fake post uses...

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I've tried that too and it failed. I added `tester.binding.addTime(Duration(minutes: 5)` and still failed because of time out.

Comment: I just found the solution thanks to your help. I'll post it down below

Comment: Forget it, the test did pass but if I change the ListView's key, the test still passes.

Comment: @10101010 No, but I think I get it why the test fails just now. I'll write the solution that I found down below.

Comment: We are waiting for your valuable solution .@AlmanteraTAlFaruqi

Comment: For some reason await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5)) is blocking all the "threads". The http request is not being made for me and the test waits forever